# want to get the value of array key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a complicated array and want to find the value of this. but the problem is answer getting like 0,1,2,3,4,5

following is the code to getting the value of state of array

```
var shardState = Object.keys(mydata.cluster.collections[collectionName].shards[String(shardName)].state);
alert(shardState);
```

Following is the array.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4},
  "cluster":{
    "collections":{
      "college":{
        "pullReplicas":"0",
        "replicationFactor":"1",
        "shards":{"shard1":{
            "range":"80000000-7fffffff",
            "state":"active",
```

Comment: i want state: active

Comment: You do not have an array. You have an object. Moreover what are the values of `collectionName` and `shardName`??

Comment: What he means is: 1/2 the variables in your code are not defined and/or have no values and you don't describe exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.  It's going to be really difficult to help you

Comment: Try removing `Object.keys` (leave only that argument)

Comment: did you read about what `Object.keys` is for?

Comment: any idea to fetch the state key value through object? if collectionName is college and shardName is shard1

Comment: @user3164151 you can see such example in last snippet of my answer (you can click "Run code snippet" to see value of `shardState`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var shardState = mydata.cluster.collections[collectionName].shards[shardName].state;
alert(shardState);

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you're doing this:

```js
console.log("Your result:", Object.keys("active"))
console.log("'active' converted to object:", Object("active"))
```

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns the keys of an object. Since you've passed a string, it returns indices of all the characters. 
So please remove `Object.keys` from your code:

```js
const mydata = {
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 4
  },
  "cluster": {
    "collections": {
      "college": {
        "pullReplicas": "0",
        "replicationFactor": "1",
        "shards": {
          "shard1": {
            "range": "80000000-7fffffff",
            "state": "active",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const collectionName = "college", shardName = "shard1";

var shardState = mydata.cluster.collections[collectionName].shards[String(shardName)].state;
console.log(shardState);
```